# Javascript Hover Content Show

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

I am attempting to write a JS function (using prototype in rails) that will show hidden divs within a li when that li is mouseover'ed. Each li has a unique id that is a number, like so:

```
<li id="100">
  <div style="display:none;" id="hover-display-content">Content</div>
  <div style="display:none;" id="more-hover-display-content">Content</div>
  <div style="display:none;" id="even-more-hover-display-content">Content</div>
</li>
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this though, especially where the JS only shows the hidden elemenst for that specific li.

I'm thinking something like:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {  
  Event.observe($("li"), 'mouseover', function() {
     var id = readAttribute("id")
     id.getElementById("hover-display-content").style.display = "inline"; 
     id.getElementById("more-hover-display-content").style.display = "inline";
     id.getElementById("even-hover-display-content").style.display = "inline";
  });  
Event.observe($("li"), 'mouseout', function() {  
     var id = readAttribute("id")
     id.getElementById("hover-display-content").style.display = "none"; 
     id.getElementById("more-hover-display-content").style.display = "none";
     id.getElementById("even-hover-display-content").style.display = "none";
});  
});
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.  Where am I going wrong?

**Edit:**

I am now using:

```
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {  
$$('li').invoke('observe', 'mouseover', function(event) {
    this.children[0].toggle();
});

$$('li').invoke('observe', 'mouseout', function(event) {
    document.children[0].toggle();
});
    });
```

Which is partially working, however my code looks like the following:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div style="display:hidden;">Hidden Div</div>
    <div>More content that isn't hidden</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I rollover the li it displays the hidden div, however if I rollover the second div it hides the comment again, even though this div is in the li.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a tag and hover? just providing an idea

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
a div{display:none; height:10px;}
a:hover div{display:inline;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a>a<div id="hover-display-content">Content</div></a></li>
  <li><a>s<div id="more-hover-display-content">Content1</div></a></li>
  <li><a>d<div id="even-more-hover-display-content">Content2</div></a></li>
</ul>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is your only issue but one key thing is that DOM id's cannot begin with a number, youll need to prefix that with something like `model_name-100`. Additionally, all `id`'s need to be unique. So your inner content `div`'s need to have those `id`'s converted to classes like `class="even-more-hover-display-content"`... or alternatively you could jsut prefix the id with the `id` of the parent element like `model_name-100-even-more-hover-display-content`.

Comment: actually my element does start with a prefix, I just took it out for brevity's sake.

Comment: @Ryan: not a good thing to do when thats important to how youre selecting and acting on things... might want to put the code back in verbatim, minus things that are confidential.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the .getElementByClass() --- deprecated in Proto 1.6

[Link here.](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/getElementsByClassName)

As a fallback plan, here's a proof-of-concept in regular JS that works:

```
<li onmouseover="this.children[0].style.display = 'inline';
                 this.children[1].style.display = 'inline';"> 
   <div id="testdiv" style="display:none;background:blue">test</div>
   <div id="testdiv" style="display:none;background:blue">test</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery

```
$('#id').each(function(){
$(this).css({diplay:'inline'});});
```

isn't that simple . .